# Linguaggio inclusivo

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

In base alla attuale situazione in Italia e/o altri paesi italoparlanti, che strategie mi raccomandereste per avere un discorso neutrale, senza favorire nessun genere? C'è qualche pronome che stia guadagnando forza al riguardo?

Comment: Se avessi molte figlie sposate, anch'io cercherei di non favorire nessun genero.

Comment: Ti raccomanderei [questo libro](https://www.uvic.cat/es/noticias/som-dones-som-linguistes-som-moltes-i-diem-prou-el-nuevo-libro-de-eumo-editorial) scritto da linguiste catalane. È scritto in catalano, ma affronta lo stesso problema. Il titolo è un buon riassunto del contenuto. Cerco di tradurlo: "Siamo donne, siamo linguiste, siamo molte e diciamo: basta! Basta con testi incoerenti e confusi. Se cambiamo il mondo la lingua cambierà".

Comment: @DaG Mi dispiace, fu un problema di 'falsi amici'

Answer (score 1):

Effettivamente c'è qualcuno che, per fini politici, promuove pubblicamente l'asterisco finale per mascherare il genere, ma in generale questa campagna non risuona né tra i principali giornali né tra le televisioni.

È un'iniziativa lasciata al singolo utente, o singolo gruppo (politicizzato), che si manifesta unicamente su Twitter o Facebook.